# SQL QUERY: If NULL then take another column but if NULL again ignore it

Tags: sql

[SQL QUERY]
Hi, I need to have a date value from a column, if this column has the value NULL het should refer to another column, this should be translated like this:

```
SELECT * ISNULL(column1, column2)
FROM [Table1]
```

But now if the second column (column2) has also a NULL value he needs to ignore it, how can I please handle this?

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: You can use `COALESCE(column1, column2, 'OMG!' )`

Comment: This is tagged with `MySQL` but the use of square brackets and the use of `ISNULL` would imply this is in fact SQL Server and not MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISNULL will do that for you.

```sql
   SELECT ISNULL(Modified, Created) as LastTouched
     FROM Table
```

If modified is null and created is null, LastTouched will be null.

If you want to filter the row if both values are null, then you need to use the where clause

```sql
   SELECT ISNULL(Modified, Created) as LastTouched
     FROM Table
    WHERE Modified IS NOT NULL OR Created IS NOT NULL
```

As a side note, you have a syntax error in your query: you are missing a comma after the star in the select clause. It has to look like this:

```
SELECT *, ISNULL(column1, column2)
FROM [Table1]
```

Coalesce is good for multiple columns/values. Not sure if there is any performance difference if only using it for two values.

EDIT:
Yes, my bad - if you want rows where either Modified or Created is not null, but not both, then you should use OR in the query - I have fixed that in the example. Thanks to @GarethD

Comment: This seems legit !! I will give it a try and let you know but thanks all for your reactions !!

Comment: Hum unfortunately, this seems not correct, the "Modified IS NOT NULL" seems to overlap the query so it ignores all the NULL... 
Maybe I'm not clear enough, let's say that "Modified" has 290 items with no NULL and "Created" has 300 items with no NULL, I need to prioritize the "modified" value but if this one is NULL it should take the value of "Created", if the last one has also NULL it should ignore it (not present in the set). So normally I should always end with 300 items, no? This is not the case with this query, I ended up with the 290 items of the "modified" column.

Comment: @Obieworld The where clause should use `OR` rather than `AND`. i.e.  `WHERE Modified IS NOT NULL OR CreatedDate IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Thx @GarethD but this gives me an insane incorrect amount, way above the 300 items supposed needed

Comment: Do you have other conditions in the `WHERE` that you haven't included in the question? If so, you may need to wrap the condition in parenthesis. e.g. `WHERE <existing conditions> AND (Column1 IS NOT NULL OR Column2 IS NOT NULL)`. It would really help though if you could post some sample data and expected output, because it is not immediately clear what you are after here.

Comment: You are totally right @GarethD !! Yes I had a condition before (sorry new in the SQL world, and it is work data so I can not give a real sample) but now it is working !! Many thanks !! actually COALESCE give me also the correct amount.